# Combinations of Generators in Python

Tags: python-3.x, generator, combinations, python-itertools

If I have a generator, and I use `itertools.combinations(generator, n)` on it, the generator I created will be empty. Is it possible to keep the generator as it is?

Example:

```
g = (i for i in range(100))
print(list(g))
combinations = itertools.combinations(g, 5)
print(list(g)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., 97, 98, 99]
[] # i want this to be same as above
```

Comment: You can only consume any iterator (including generators) once. After the first `list(g)`, `g` has nothing left to yield.

Comment: You'd need to store the result of `list(g)`; once it's consumed, future `list` calls will return `[]`.

Comment: You can also use `itertools.tee` to split the generator, then pass the result to `combinations`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem It's worth noting that `itertools.tee` consumes memory proportional to the distance between the tee iterators. If one of the iterators is going to be fully consumed before the next iterator starts, it would be more efficient to just use `list`.